# In Entity Framework, is it possible to auto-map a column to an entity property? ID => [tablename]ID

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I want to use .Id in my entity classes for the unique id, but our dba wants [tablename]Id in the database tables. Is there a way that Entity Framework can make this mapping automatically without having to create a new map file for every entity?

Comment: Do you consider using fluent mapping within the context (one line for each ID) to be too much? there's also `ColumnAttribute`, but that would also mean opening each entity and decorating the property.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do this? I don't know of any other way other than creating a map for the entity and adding it to the modelBuilder configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as I understand you correctly, you have something like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    // ...
}
public class Bar
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

And, without too much effort (or creating multiple `entityTypeConfiguration<T>` models) you'd like something along the lines of the following outcome:

```
Current Mapping                  Desired Mapping

[Foo]                            [Foo]
  ID                               FooID
  ...                              ...
[Bar]                            [Bar]
  ID                               BarID
  ...                              ...
```

For this, a few methods exist (and depend on which version of EF you're using). With that said, some approachable tactics:

**ColumnAttribute**

You can visit each entity model and decorate the ID property with the `ColumnAttribute`. This tells EF that, despite what *we* named the column, we want *something else* to be the name within the database. e.g.

```
public class Foo
{
    [Column("FooID")]
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    // ...
}
public class Foo
{
    [Column("BarID")]
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

The only problem here is that you're now going to every model and adding the attribute.

**OnModelCreating & Fluent Mapping**

Another method is to do the mapping but keep it all in one place. The `OnModelCreating` event is great for this kind of thing.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public Dbset<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnmodelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .Property(x => x.ID).HasColumnName("FooID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>()
            .Property(x => x.ID).HasColumnName("BarID");
    }
}
```

Again, the problem here is that you're creating a configuration for each entity.

**Custom Conventions**

As of EF6, you can use Custom Conventions which make things easier (Including developing your own convention that would make `ID`=`TableNameID`). Unfortunately I don't have the time to write an example, but the [docs](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions) are pretty enlightening.

Comment: This is perfect! I'm using code-first approach, so adding the column attribute is the perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

According to MSDN , [both way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.idkeydiscoveryconvention%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) should work.

> Primary key detection is case insensitive. Recognized naming patterns
>   are, in order of precedence: 'Id' [type name]Id

Comment: I don't think that was the question (unless I mis-read). I think they were looking to keep `ID` and make it save as `TableNameID` (but without the need to decorate/configure every entity individually). [or at least that's how I read it]